# Azure BLOB storage phantom requests

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I see strange requests when uploading blobs to storage. The only methods I use is **PutBlob** and **SetBlobTier**. But metrics shows large amount of **GetBlobProperties** requests with time interval about 1 hour.  It seems like Azure makes some extra requests for statistic purposes. It happens only when uploading process is running. At attached diagram you can see 4 peaks of GetBlobProperties requests. 
[image: Screenshot of diagram with 4 GetBlobProperties sections]
Does anybody know what is it? Another question is, will I be billed for this requests?

Comment: Was the proposed answer helpful to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any API call is considered to be a transaction:

**Transactions** – ***Each individual Blob, Table and Queue REST request to the storage service is considered as a potential transaction for billing***. Applications can then control their transaction costs by controlling how often and how many requests they send to the storage service. We analyze each request received and then classify it as billable or not billable based upon our ability to process the request and the request’s outcome.

For that specific transaction, my guess is you're using Blob Archive(correct me if i'm wrong), the prices are as below:

[image]

It will be considered as **All other Operations(per 10,000)** pricing.

```
What could be causing it?
```

Due to a bug in our system, some internal transactions are miscategorized as customer requests when blobs transition between cold and archive storage tiers. These unexpected transactions will also be visible in both Azure Monitor as well as Storage Analytics logging. We are working on a fix for this and will deploy it as soon as possible. We apologize for any inconvenience and confusion this may have caused.

Comment: Thank ypu Adam! Now I receive an Invoice from Azure, and I can confirm that GetBlobProperties transactions (even if you dont make them) a billable.

Comment: Thanks @dsky please upvote or mark as answer if the proposed answer was helpul to you, to help other members of the community asking a similar question :)

Comment: The question contains of two parts, billing - is the second one, another is about source of GetBlobProperties transactions. What about first one, I asked it in Azure-support, and they said, that they can't find the reason. I use storge explorer, but GetBlobProperties requests appears even if storage explorer is not running. I enabled logging in portal and it shows that transactions came from IP 91.203.194.209, that is not from Azure pool and not mine too. So the main problem is not solved, I still receive large amount of transactions. But now I surely know that I will pay for them.

Comment: a quick nslookup doesn't get a registered domain to that IP, but if you put the IP on a browser, I'm getting a Website in Russian: try putting the IP in a webbrowser: 91.203.194.209 , do you own that website ? or is any of your storage content is on there ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally put in comment wrong IP address. The correct one is: 10.116.96.67

Comment: Just for clarify: GetBlobProperties transactions came from IP 10.116.96.67

Comment: ok, Can you give me the support request number you have ? I'll check on it first thing tomorrow(I'm in the west coast). 
Aslo, have you tried configuring the firewal on your storage account? 
here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security

Comment: Log records look like this: 1.0;2018-08-14T17:39:31.4884797Z;GetBlobProperties;SASSuccess;200;2;2;sas;;kdphotostorage;blob;"https://kdphotostorage.blob.core.windows.net/objects/19085626?sp=rw&amp;spr=https&amp;se=9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z&amp;sk=system-1&amp;sv=2016-02-19&amp;sr=b&amp;sig=XXXXX&amp;api-version=2017-07-29";"/kdphotostorage/objects/19085626";2ecbb2e1-501e-0064-76f5-33d185000000;0;10.116.96.67:64935;2017-07-29;545;0;519;0;0;;;"&quot;0x8D601FDF9317752&quot;";Tuesday, 14-Aug-18 15:52:43 GMT;;"Azure-Storage/9.1.1 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.42000; Win32NT 6.2.9200.0)";;"..."

Comment: Thank you Adam! Support request number is 118081418783950