# Azure BLOB storage - many transactions

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have loaded 1844 files to Azure to hot storage. I use AzCopy program from Microsoft. In metrics right now  200 000 transactions. What's going on? Why 200K transactions? I found this request with BUG in Azure.
[Azure BLOB storage phantom requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827955/azure-blob-storage-phantom-requests)

[screen from dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbkgS.jpg)

my command:

azcopy /Source:**LocalPath** /Dest:https://**mystorage**.blob.core.windows.net/img/ /DestKey:**AccessKey** /S

Comment: It could be that each block upload is a transaction. When you upload a file as a block blob, each part is sent in a separate request.

Comment: You haven't included any details about the size of your files. As @juunas mentioned, every block will be uploaded within a single transaction. Blocks can be from 4MB to 100MB. So it's possible that dozens of transactions are required for a given file. Not sure why you've jumped to the conclusion that there's a bug.

Comment: Thank you, David. My files are about 450 MB. I have understood what packing files in zip doesn't decrease price of upload.  440 MB/4 MB=110 transactions. It was my wrong conclusion after search in Google.

Comment: There is param for AzCopy for changing block size from 4 MB to 100 MB? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters  I can't find.

Answer (score 1):

In this doc :[Understanding Windows Azure Storage Billing – Bandwidth, Transactions, and Capacity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/), you could find something under `Uploading Blobs`. It says `When uploading a blob greater than 32 Mbytes, the storage client library will break it into 4 Mbyte blocks by default.`  and `Each PutBlock will count as 1 transaction, and the final PutBlockList will also count as 1 transaction`.

The other thing is from the official doc:[Transfer Data with the Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library), you could know the Storage Client Library is the core of AzCopy.
So the conclusion is established.

With Storage Client Library, you could change the default block size, however AzCopy doesn't mention it so maybe it's not changeable.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! There is param for AzCopy  [/BlockSizeInMB:]. I used this param for files less than 100 MB. 
500 transactions were for 250 files. 
2500 transactions were without  param [/BlockSizeInMB:]. 
Now full command is:
azcopy /Source:**LocalPath** /Dest:https://**mystorage**.blob.core.windows.net/img/ /DestKey:**AccessKey** /S /BlockSizeInMB:**[100MB]**
Save your money!